# SpriteKit - drawing circles containing other circles with physics body

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I am new to Objective-C and I am trying to make a simple spriteKit game which contains a circle and a ball inside it. I want to move the ball around in this circle as well on the iPhone movement. So far I have created the circle and am able to put the ball on the screen.

My problem is that I am not sure the ball is actually inside the circle or on top of it. When I attach a physics body on the ball, it drops out of the screen and does not stop on the circle's bottom edge. I am using SKShapeNode for both the circle and ball.

Please help me to provide the right documentation to go through or a little piece of code that can resolve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Generally, people prefer to see some code which demonstrates your problem; it makes it easier for people to see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign appropriate physics bodies to your nodes. See [Simulating Physics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW1) in the Sprite Kit Programming Guide.

From your description, it sounds like you need to create the outter circle's physics body with the [bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) method (and provide a path representing the circle). Note that an edge loop physics body is not [dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic) and can only collide with volume-based bodies.

The inner balls physics body can be created with [bodyWithCircleOfRadius:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithCircleOfRadius%3a).

Comment: Thanks a million @Janis K, that what i needed to do. It works. thanks again